# Visual Studio 2010 post build event completely ignored

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

I was looking on stackoverflow for anything similiar to my issue but without results.

```
It seems that my VS started to completely ignore post-build events. 
Post-build events are not triggered in any project or solution I open
or create using my VS 2010.
```

I don't know why and from when, but previously (a couple of weeks ago) it was working fine. And I haven't changed project configuration nor VS installation on my own. There were a couple of windows update though, but since I dont know from when it is not working, I can not specify them. I want post-build event to be triggered, but it never is, no matter how simple it is. The project configuration is fine, since it is working for my team mates (on their machines).

Trying to figure out what is happening, I did:

- created test project
- disabled all plugins (CodeMaid, VSAssistX, etc.)
- created pre-build, pre-link and post-build events that simply echo something (and ofcourse enabled them in project properties (Use in build -> Yes)).

The result is that I see echos and VS messages about pre-build and pre-link build event, but nothing about post-build event (btw I'm using Qt add-in):

```
    1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>Build started 2013-02-07 11:03:54.
    1>_PrepareForClean:
    1>  Deleting file "Debug\Test.lastbuildstate".
    1>InitializeBuildStatus:
    1>  Creating "Debug\Test.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
    1>PreBuildEvent:
    1>  prebuild
    1>CustomBuild:
    1>  Moc'ing Test.hpp...
    1>  Uic'ing Test.ui...
    1>  Rcc'ing Test.qrc...
    1>RCC : warning : No resources in 'C:\Projects\BuildEvents\Test\Test\Test.qrc'.
    1>  
    1>ClCompile:
    1>  moc_Test.cpp
    1>  main.cpp
    1>  Test.cpp
    1>  Generating Code...
    1>  qrc_Test.cpp
    1>PreLinkEvent:
    1>  prelink
    1>qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc100.pdb' was not found with 'qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj)' or at 'C:\Projects\BuildEvents\Test\vc100.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
    1>  Test.vcxproj -> C:\Projects\BuildEvents\Test\Test.exe
    1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
    1>  Deleting file "Debug\Test.unsuccessfulbuild".
    1>  Touching "Debug\Test.lastbuildstate".
    1>
    1>Build succeeded.
    1>
    1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.80
    ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I suspect that problem is with Visual Studio itself, but maybe you have any better ideas what might be causing that and how to solve it?

Comment: What is RunPostBuildEvent set to in your csproj file?

Comment: I have the same issue with pre build event being ignored in VS 2012 ONLY if I start the build with msbuild.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just created script that I run manually after each build. This is stupid solution, because when any of my teammates will do some changes that require changes in post-build, I will need to change my script too.